# take action once background script is killed

Tags: shell, scripting, kill, signals

I have below script running as background process.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
:
done

email_kill_alert() {
echo "" | mailx -s "scritp received kill signal." emailid
}
```

Above script is run as background process with `nohup` command. I want it to trigger `email_kill_alert` function to send out email as soon as script or process ID gets killed. I have been reading about use of `trap` but not sure how I implement it. Note that while loop is infinite as it constantly checks for a files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this before the while loop: `trap 'email_kill_alert' KILL`

Comment: I would suggest to use `SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGINT` instead of `KILL`.

Comment: How can trapping `KILL` work? `SIGKILL` can’t be caught (or ignored).

Comment: Thank you so much guys. it worked. I used below, above while loop.
trap 'email_kill_alert' SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGINT

Comment: There is another problem here. I run above script with command "nohup bash scirpt.sh &" in background. When I use "kill PID", it sends email but PID still running. And when I use "kill -9 PID", it does not send email and PID is killed. How can I make sure using "kill PID" command, it kills PID with email sent and using "kill -9 PID" it sends email with PID killed?